# How to pass parameters from VB.NET To SSRS Report without using Report.SetParameters()

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services, printing

I have an SSRS report with english and arabic content ,i convert the report in VB.NET to stream of bytes and then send it to printer to print report ,without using report viewer.When i pass parameters from vb.net to ssrs using Report.SetParameters() the arabic content in the report reverses in some cases and it behaves abnormally (some letters in few words are reversed ,some are in correct order.Some words are reversed completely).The report prints correctly if i use report viewer and click on view report and print the report and it works fine on the report server however when i use VB.NET and pass parameters to SSRS the arabic content coming from database (AS400) behaves abnormally.I wanted to know if there is a way to pass parameters without using ReportViewer.SetParameters()

What i tried and why i came to this conclusion
1)I manually set parameters IN ssrs report with values ,and printed the report from vb.net application and didnt pass any parameters from VB.NET To SRRS .Report was printing correctly

2)I ran the report in report server in browser and passed the parameters in query string and the arabic content was printing correctly on report server .

I tried passing this full url in VB.NET using ReportPath() but that doesnt work

```
  rptPrinting.ServerReport.ReportPath = http://ServerName/ReportServer/UT
%20Documents/VHRSSALEPDU001&p1=W&p2=00150&p3=10&p4=28578&p5=Test&p6=Y
```

I wanted to know if there is some way other than Report.SetParameters() to send parameters like through query string from VB.NET to SSRS .So that i dont get the abnormal behaviour with arabic content .

My code where i pass parameters

```
 report.ReportServerUrl = New System.Uri(ldtReportParameter.Rows(0).Item("RMREPTSERV").ToString.Trim)
        report.ReportPath = ldtReportParameter.Rows(0).Item("RMREPTPATH").ToString.Trim

            laIndividualParameters(0) = New ReportParameter("p1", row.Cells(4).Text.ToString().Trim(), False)
            laIndividualParameters(1) = New ReportParameter("p2", row.Cells(5).Text.ToString().Trim(), False)
            laIndividualParameters(2) = New ReportParameter("p3", row.Cells(6).Text.ToString().Trim(), False)
            laIndividualParameters(3) = New ReportParameter("p4", row.Cells(3).Text.ToString().Trim(), False)
            laIndividualParameters(4) = New ReportParameter("p5", row.Cells(2).Text.ToString().Trim(), False)
            laIndividualParameters(5) = New ReportParameter("p6", row.Cells(7).Text.ToString().Trim(), False)

             report.SetParameters(laIndividualParameters)
            ServerExport(report)//Function to convert report to stream of bytes and send to printer
```

Comment: Parameters in a URL are after a question mark and the parameter are separated by an amphersand.  From : VHRSSALEPDU001&p1=W  To : VHRSSALEPDU001?p1=W

Comment: it was my typing mistake,i corrected it.I had originally used ? mark only

Comment: Is code working?

Comment: No,i get this error when i try to render the report to PDF ,The path of the item '/UT Documents/VHRSSALEPDU001?p1=W&p2=00150&p3=10&p4=38578&p5=Test&p6=Y' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash

Comment: What you posted is only 46 characters long.  Something must be adding the network namespace to the string.

Comment: I dont have the reference for the article ,but i read somewhere that we cannot pass parameters in ReportPath .That Report path should only be like this '/UT Documents/VHRSSALEPDU001

Comment: That doesn't resolve issue with the length being 260 characters?  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: yeah the issue isnt with the length and that report path cannot be used to send parameters,it is only to point the report location in the report server

Comment: Did you read the link?  It clearly show the question mark and parameters.

Comment: I followed the link and changed my URL accordingly getting  Missing End Point Exception The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

Comment: Can you put your URL into a browser and get the report?  there could be three reasons for failure 1) The browser/http settings in c# 2) The URL is bad (including parameters) 3) The connection string in report to database may not correct or bad credentials.

Comment: i am getting the report when i directly paste the URL in browser

Comment: Do that include the parameters?  Pararemeters in a URL are after a question mark.  A lot of times when working with a browser the default HTTP headers are different in c# from other tools/apps.  The solution is to add or change the default header.   What browser are you using?  The browser is defined by the UserAgent Header. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent.  You are using HTTP so you can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the HTTP header of c# with the working browser to determne a solution.

Comment: I copy pasted this url in the browser http://ServerName/ReportServer?/UT+Documents/VHRSSALEPDU001&prsFRANCHISE=W&prsBRAN=00150&prsDEPT=10&prsPRNO=38578&prsCopy=Test&prsBanner=Y  and i got the report .My browser is IE 11 .I will use fiddler and try what u said,i have never used fiddler or wireshark before